# Pass variable name as argument dynamically on svydesign and dplyr::select functions

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm newbie with R. There is a code like the following, and for that code, variable name `wt_itvex_divided_by_4` should be dynamically replaced with `wt_itvex_divided_by_3` or `wt_itvex_divided_by_2`

```
df_odds_sv <- as_survey(
  svydesign(id = ~psu+ID_fam,
            strata = ~kstrata,
            weights = ~wt_itvex_divided_by_4,
            data = data_sd1013
            )) %>%
  dplyr::select(ID, ID_fam, psu, kstrata, wt_itvex_divided_by_4) %>%
  subset(ID %in% df_odds$ID)
```

To implement dynamical change, I tried something like the following by using `temp` variable, but it didn't work

```
temp='wt_itvex_divided_by_3'

df_odds_sv <- as_survey(
  svydesign(id = ~psu+ID_fam,
            strata = ~kstrata,
            weights = ~temp,
            data = data_sd1013
            )) %>%
  dplyr::select(ID, ID_fam, psu, kstrata, temp) %>%
  subset(ID %in% df_odds$ID)
```

Or, by some search on this problem, I saw someone recommended to use `get()`, so I tried like the following. It didn't create the error but `wt_itvex_divided_by_3` column wasn't selected

```
s<-'wt_itvex_divided_by_3'

df_odds_sv <- as_survey(
  svydesign(id = ~psu+ID_fam,
            strata = ~kstrata,
            weights = ~get(s),
            data = data_sd1013
            )) %>%
  dplyr::select(ID, ID_fam, psu, kstrata, get(s)) %>%
  subset(ID %in% df_odds$ID)
```

---

Referencing Ronak Shah's answer, I solved the issue by the following code (note that I used arguments differently for svydesign's weights and dplyr::select)

```
temp='wt_itvex_divided_by_3'

df_odds_sv <- as_survey(
  svydesign(id = ~psu+ID_fam,
            strata = ~kstrata,
            weights = ~data_sd1013[[temp]],
            data = data_sd1013
            )) %>%
  dplyr::select(ID, ID_fam, psu, kstrata, temp) %>%
  subset(ID %in% df_odds$ID)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try subsetting from the dataframe directly with `[[`.

Using `apistrat` data as an example.

```
library(survey)
library(srvyr)
data(api)

temp= "pw"

dstrat1 <- svydesign(id=~1,strata=~stype, weights= ~apistrat[[temp]],
                     data=apistrat, fpc=~fpc)
```